# NodeJs library to convert ESRI point(x, y, wkid) to lat/lng

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, software-recommendations, node-js

I use ArcGIS and get an array of ESRI points which I need to convert to lat/lng.

I don't want to use the ArcGIS API, because it requires too many calls. Is there any library that can do the work for me?

Comment: What is an ESRI point?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [proj4.js](http://proj4js.org/). Just install it using `npm install proj4`.

From the documentation:

```js
var firstProjection = 'PROJCS["NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42.68333333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",41.71666666666667],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",41],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-71.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",200000],PARAMETER["false_northing",750000],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26986"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]';
var secondProjection = "+proj=gnom +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=6300000 +y_0=6300000 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
//I'm not going to redefine those two in latter examples.
proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[2,5]);
// [-2690666.2977344505, 3662659.885459918]
```

You would have to write the definition for your spatial reference and then just convert to WGS84.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a simple library for that - @esri/arcgis-rest-geocoding.
using reverseGeocode function, it works perfectly.